# bool value for a double pointer (exists/empty or not)

Tags: c++, arguments

I am reading some code sample that sounds odd to me:

Method argument is a pointer to double. In method body, there a conditional statement testing whether this argument pointer is given or not (empty or not). I wonder how the pointer can have a bool value, and what is the syntax for non-existant pointer (NULL? 0?).

Here is the method implementation :

```
bool OMethod::initSim(double* alpha_)
{
int i, j;
const double * cparameters = fun->getParameters();
simplex = OMatrix::allocMatrix(npts,ndim,true);
sSum = new double[ndim];
funcEvals = new double[npts]; 
double *alpha = 0;
     if(!alpha_) {
alpha = new double[ndim];
    for(i = 0; i< ndim; ++i) {
    if(cparameters[i] == 0)
        alpha[i] = 0.2f;
    else
        alpha[i] = 0.1 * cparameters[i];
        }
}
else
{
    alpha = alpha_;
}

     for(j = 0; j < npts; ++j) 
 {
    for(i = 0; i < ndim; ++i)
    sim[j][i] = cparameters[i]
      }

delete [] cparameters;

for(j = 0; j < ndim; ++j)
{
    sim[j + 1][j] += alpha[j];
}

computeS();

for(i = 0; i < npts; ++i) 
{
    funcEvals[i] = evalFunc(simplex[i]);    
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, a pointer value is considered "true" in a boolean context (e.g. in an `if` test or `!` expression) when it is not equal to zero, i.e. it is not null. So, `!alpha` is the same as `alpha == 0`, `alpha == NULL` and `alpha == nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

It checks if the pointer value is 0 (null). The `if (alpha_)` part can also be written as `if (alpha_ != 0)`.'

Example:

```
int *add(int *array, int n, int *sum) {
  if (sum == 0) {
     sum = new int;
     *sum = 0;
  }
  *sum += array[0];
  if (n > 0)
     add(array+1, n-1, sum);
  return sum;
}

main() {
  int a[] =  {1,2,3};
  int *sum = 0;
  sum = add(a, 3, sum);
  // ...
  delete sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test any value against 0 (or in the case of pointers, NULL) in C++ by writing `!`.

Answer (score 0):

For normal pointers to simple types, `if (!pointer)` is equivalent to `if (pointer==NULL)`.